# Post Oreo 8.0+ Action_User_Present Workaround?

Tags: c#, android

I want to have my app open up every single time the device is unlocked.  Effectively, I need a consistent replacement for ACTION_USER_PRESENT.

---

**(NOTE THIS IS FOR AN INTERDISCIPLINARY, PEER-REVIEWED ACADEMIC STUDY STARTING SOON AND IS VITAL FOR THE STUDY'S SUCCESS)**

Before the Oero 8.0 update, ACTION_USER_PRESENT was a perfect way to start up the android app each time the device was unlocked.

Unfortunately the work-arounds I've been trying to use are just not cutting it.  Effectively I've assigned a myBroadastReceiver to attempt to run the app and PowerManager to see if the device is on or not. Depending on if the device is being used will impact if in the myBroadcastReceiver code will Initiate an Intent.

Problem 1) The broadcast receiver can only be assigned to run at minimum every 15 minutes. I need it to run every time the device unlocks.

Problem 2) Sometimes the broadcast receiver doesnt even try to run for hours at a time... as if the assigned 15 minute check is more of a loose suggestion and not an explicit command.

SOME CODE:

public class classMyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context contextOfReceive, Intent intentOfReceive) {

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //This loads up the user selected settings choosen at the homepage of the application.
    final SharedPreferences internalAppInformation = contextOfReceive.getSharedPreferences("userPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = internalAppInformation.edit();
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Code used to determine 2 things
    // 1) if the Device being used or inactive
    // 2) if the activity has already been prompted earlier and therefore should be in the foreground of the device
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) contextOfReceive.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean booleanIsScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
    boolean booleanIsActivityUp = internalAppInformation.getBoolean("booleanIsActivityUp", false);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //If Screen is Off (i.e. the device is NOT BEING USED AT THE MOMENT)
    //then this code should allow the Activity to Start
    if ( (!booleanIsActivityUp)&&(!booleanIsScreenOn) ) {
        //Initiates and Starts up the Intent PromptAndClose.class

        editor.putBoolean("booleanIsActivityUp", true);
        editor.commit();
        editor.apply();

        //THE REST OF THE CODE BELOW IS JUST CHOOSING AND
        // INITIATING THE PROGRAM AND IS NOT PROBLEMATIC.

    }

}
```

More detailed code can be provided if it will be helpful.  I am worried that more code will result it too much clutter for the reader.

ADDITIONAL CODE TO DESCRIBE WHEN THE myBroadcastReceiver is Initiated.

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Sets up and starts the calendar (with the setAlarm method for re-occuring attempts to 
    //prompt the app to move to the foreground if the right conditions are met.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

    Log.i("Calendar", "Set Calendar >=23");
    calendar.set(
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            30
    );


    setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    int time = (int) calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    String timeString = String.valueOf(time);
    Log.i("TIME", "time: " + timeString);

}

private void setAlarm(long timeInMillis) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, classMyBroadcastReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    assert alarmManager != null;

    //RTC-Fires the pending intent at the specified time but does not wake up the device.
    //The shortest interval is INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES.
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, timeInMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);

}
```

}

This code is present in the main activity of the application.  The concept is that the first time the app is installed and ran, it will run this code and start and continuous loop of checking and displaying the app to the foreground of the device if the device is not being used.  Once that intent is interacted with by the user and closed, the loop starts up again.

Comment: "Unfortunately the work-arounds I've been trying to use are just not cutting it" -- please provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you are trying. A foreground service registering the receiver via `registerReceiver()` should work.

Comment: Additional Code has been added.

Comment: OK, but where are you registering this receiver? For example, you have "The broadcast receiver can only be assigned to run at minimum every 15 minutes", and I do not know what that means. Again, a foreground service registering the receiver via `registerReceiver()` should work.

Comment: Sorry about that CommonsWare. I looked throughout the entire program and was unable to identify "registerReceiver()".

Answer (score 1):

That is not going to work. Doze mode and app standby will make what you are trying to do very unreliable.

Try this: Create a foreground service. Start that foreground service when you need to start receiving this broadcast. In `onCreate()` of that service, call `registerReceiver()` register a receiver for `ACTION_USER_PRESENT`. So long as your service is running, you will receive the `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` broadcast as before.

Comment: Just out of curisity, wasn't the Action_User_Present broadcast reciever (along with many other implicit broadcasts) removed during the 8.0+ Oreo update in December of 2017?

Comment: @AndrewB.: None of those were removed. They were changed to behave like some others (e.g,. `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`) that only deliver their broadcasts to dynamically registered receivers.